# Adjective rank for price/cost of product or purchase

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I've found [numerous pages](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/british-grammar/adjectives-order) listing the [correct order](https://theeditorsblog.net/2014/04/08/keeping-adjectives-in-line/) of adjectives.  While some disagree on the number of ranks, all have the ranks they do list are in this order:

1. Determiner/quantity
2. Observation or Opinion
3. Size
4. Temperature
5. Shape
6. Age
7. Color
8. Origin
9. Material
10. Purpose
11. Qualifier

However, none of the pages I've found have described which group the numeric price of the thing fits into.

Some have listed "costly" and its synonyms in group two, and that is my guess as well.  [Some sites](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/ordering-multiple-adjectives/) list "value" in group two, but none of the examples I've found have explicitly listed a dollar amount.

> They can afford a $500 WiFi-enabled auto-scooping litter box.

or

> They can afford a $500, WiFi-enabled auto-scooping litter box.

Note the comma following the price in the second sentence.

If price is in the same rank as *WiFi-enabled*--an observation/quality--then the following sentence should sound right, but it does not.

> They can afford a WiFi-enabled, $500 auto-scooping litter box.

However, there is no group in any of the sites I've found between quantity and observation.

Should I place a comma after *$500*?

Comment: If you think there are other-priced litter boxes like that, skip the comma to specify the $500 one. The comma says "a $500 **and** WiFi-enabled..."